# prove by induction the following inequality,How?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$ be positive numbers. Prove that

$$\frac{1}{1+x_1}+\frac{1}{1+x_1+x_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n} <  \left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{1/2}$$

this is what I can think of, but I don't know how to continue.

$$n=1$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x_{1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt[ 2]{x_{1}}}$$
$$1+x_{1}>x_{1}$$
$$a)\text{ if } x_{1}>1$$
$$x_{1}>\sqrt[ 2]{x_{1}}$$
$$x+1>\sqrt[ 2]{x_{1}}$$
$$b) \text{ if }0<x_{1}<1$$
$$x_{1}<\sqrt[ 2]{x_{1}}$$
$$0<\sqrt[ 2]{x_{1}}<1$$
$$1+x_{1}>\sqrt[ 2]{x_{1}}$$
$$\therefore\  x_ {1}\text{ positive}$$
$$\frac{1}{x_{1}+1}<\frac{1}{\sqrt[ 2]{x_1}}$$

Comment: *Hint*: $\dfrac1{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k}<\dfrac 1{x_k}$. Actually, inducrion is not necessary.

Comment: In your proof of $n=1$, it seems like you didn't square both sides.